# How do I format a date string in a Windows Form using SQL?

Tags: windows-forms-designer

I'm new to using Windows Forms and am not sure how I can format the date time I am receiving from my date input box. All I want is DD/MM/YY without the time ([Where it says Latest Transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krmfO.png). Formatting the `ToString` doesn't seem to be accepted in this context, I don't know how to apply it to what I've written without breaking things.

```cs
private void GetTotInc() {
    try {
        Con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select Sum(IncAmt) from IncomeTbl where IncUser='" + LogIn.User + "'", Con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        TotIncLbl.Text = "£" + dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        Con.Close();
    } catch (Exception) {
        Con.Close();
    }
}
```

Tried formatting the `ToString()` and did not work

Comment: What is supposed to be the datetime value? dt.Rows[0][0] is a number I guess? Try saving it to a DateTime variable and then formatting it with ToString(). And you should check sql injection: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html Which can happen in your query. And disposing the sql connection (but first your datetime question).